# Default Length Attribute for <select multiple="multiple">

Tags: html

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="2">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

If there is no option available, it shrinks and looks bad. Is there any attribute where I can specify the default length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give it a [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) via CSS, for example:

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="2" style="width: 200px;">
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/V2EsM/).

Answer (score 2):

you can use CSS to specify a width and height, so that no matter what options are available, the size of the select element stays the same:

```
select { width: 12em; height: 6em }
```

> sample:
>   http://jsfiddle.net/3PQ92/
>   http://jsfiddle.net/3PQ92/1/
>   http://jsfiddle.net/3PQ92/2/